# How is it possible to style the selected element within a select element?

Tags: css

I have a `select` element with multiple `option`s inside. I also have a text input with a `datalist` full of `option`s.

What's maddening is that if I style `option { font-size: 14pt }`, it styles all the `option`s in the `select` dropdown, but *none* of the `option`s within the `input type='text'` dropdown. They're all `option` elements, and I can't find in my books or on Google why this style would only apply to some of them.

Nor does it style the *selected* `option`. When it's in the dropdown list, it's styled. But if it's sitting as the currently-selected element, it isn't. Again, it's always an `option` element, so why would the style not apply to it everywhere?

Comment: @Amit the dropdown of suggestions that appears when a `datalist` is specified for it.

Comment: Have you got an example of the html you're using?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. I don't use select elements at all. You can instead use a readonly input textbox for display and a `<ul>` list that is hidden until the textbox is focussed where each `<li>` updates the value of the textbox on click.

Comment: Not using select elements at all is really bad practice. You should reconsider :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do what you are trying to achieve. You can, to a certain extent style the select box but not the options.

To style the select box you'll need to remove the default styling using the **appearance** property and then apply your css:

```
select {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
   background: red;
   font-size: 16px;
}
```

If you really need to style options you have to create a faux select element with other html elements. e.g. a list with list items instead of options:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

The same applies for the data list.

Not using default form elements (i.e. creating faux elements) just to fit in with design can have impacts on accessibility. It's always best to weight up the pros and cons.

If accessibility isn't a concern go for gold!